# DataGridView - changing cell format after writing data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView (DGV) object which is populated by a method which dynamically adjusts the number of columns and takes column header information from the first row of data. I have no choice but to set the column names AFTER the DGV object has been populated (the column names can also change depending on the data they contain).

However, occasionally the source data contains dates. I know the cell format can be set at the time of creation but for me this assumes I know the number of columns and type of data in advance. So my question is, is it possible to set the data type property for a specific cell to DateTime AFTER all the data has been populated and have this actually take effect so that I can actually sort by date? I tried it, but the data is still treated as text and sorting takes place based on the alphabet (not date).

I've seen various examples where it is done  at source and in an ideal world I would re-write my method to accommodate this requirement, but I'm an amateur and looking for a quick win :)

Anybody?
Thanks

Comment: When you populate your DataGridView is it through Data Source or Binding or you manually (actually programmatically) populate it?

Comment: Programatically, by converting an ArrayList of strings to a table